# What is the meaning of ogi and gi in this SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

This is the code. Can someone please explain what gi and ogi mean in this statement?

```
UPDATE `oceansne_website08`.`oc_gallery_image_description` ogi
LEFT Join  `gallery_image_to_album` gi ON gi.image_id = ogi.gallery_image_id
SET
`gallery_album_id` = gi.album_id
WHERE ogi.gallery_album_id =0;
```

Comment: That is an alias: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html (Search for _alias_ on that page)

Comment: To continue on the previous comment, aliases can (and should) be used to make a query more readable. Instead of writing the full table name you just write the alias, i.e gi.album_id. Alias can be used for column names, table names, sub queries etc and are supported in all(?) DBMS. There are some situations where they are mandatory but that is more DBMS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that you have a table called `MyVeryLongTableNameThatIFindTediousToWrite` and you want to join that to `MyEvenLongerAndMoreTediousTableWithAnEvenLongerName`

You could write:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.MyVeryLongTableNameThatIFindTediousToWrite 
INNER JOIN  myotherdb.MyEvenLongerAndMoreTediousTableWithAnEvenLongerName 
ON mydb.MyVeryLongTableNameThatIFindTediousToWrite.id = myotherdb.MyEvenLongerAndMoreTediousTableWithAnEvenLongerName.otherId 
WHERE myotherdb.MyEvenLongerAndMoreTediousTableWithAnEvenLongerName.value > 100
```

To make it more legible, you can use an Alias, so the same select can be written as:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.MyVeryLongTableNameThatIFindTediousToWrite tbla
INNER JOIN  myotherdb.MyEvenLongerAndMoreTediousTableWithAnEvenLongerName  tblb
ON tbla.id = tblb.otherId 
WHERE tblb.value > 100
```

In some  SQL flavours, you need to write `mydb.MyVeryLongTableNameThatIFindTediousToWrite AS tbla` instead, but that is slightly off-topic for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Its an alias; a shortened form of referencing the tables in your example.

```
   UPDATE `oceansne_website08`.`oc_gallery_image_description` ogi
LEFT JOIN `gallery_image_to_album` gi 
       ON gi.image_id = ogi.gallery_image_id
      SET `gallery_album_id` = gi.album_id
    WHERE ogi.gallery_album_id =0
```

Here ogi refers to the table -->`oceansne_website08`.`oc_gallery_image_description`
 and gi refers to the table --> `gallery_image_to_album`